# ProFTPD with OpenSSL error, help

Tags: ftp, openssl

I'm receiving this error message while trying to start Proftpd server on a 12.04 Ubuntu server:

```
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: mod_tls/2.4.3: compiled using OpenSSL version 'OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011' headers, but linked to OpenSSL version 'OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012' library
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: mod_sftp/0.9.8: compiled using OpenSSL version 'OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011' headers, but linked to OpenSSL version 'OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012' library
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: mod_tls_memcache/0.1: notice: unable to register 'memcache' SSL session cache: Memcache support not enabled
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: warning: unable to determine IP address of '<"my_chosen_server_name">'
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: warning: unable to determine IP address of '<"my_chosen_server_name">'
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: ProFTPD terminating (signal 11)
<"my_chosen_server_name"> proftpd[5897]: FTP session closed.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
                                                                     [fail]
```

> Of course the <"my_chosen_server_name"> was edited by me while posting the error message.

Has someone already solved that problem !?